# Убрать циклическую переадресацию htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, регулярные-выражения

Есть страница site.ru/page , нужно чтобы она редиректила на site.ru/page/superpage
Вот что я написал:
**Redirect 301 /page http://site.ru/page/superpage/**

А вот что выводится:
На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация.
И в url http://site.ru/page/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/superpage/

Насколько я понял проблема в том, что редирект идет не конкретно со страницы site.ru/page а со всех страниц которые начинаются с этого. Как это поправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page$  
RewriteRule .+ http://site.ru/page/superpage/ [R=301,L]
```