# .htaccess редирект каталога в Bitrix

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, redirect, apache2, mod-rewrite

Не могу разобраться в чем прикол.

Имею .htaccess, в котором добавил правило:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog1(.*)$ /catalog1/catalog2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

чтобы получить редирект со всех `catalog1/page` на `catalog1/catalog2/page`

в итоге получаю чуть ли не бесконечный редирект с URI типа:
http://site.ru/catalog1/catalog2//catalog2/catalog2/catalog2/..../page

Comment: Не оно ли? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/240200/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: Не совсем . Там про конкретную страницу, а я пишу про динамические page после catalog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя правило прописано так, что все запросы вида `catalog1(.*)`, где `(.*)` - любые остальные символы, редиректят на `/catalog1/catalog2/`, но данный редирект подходит под правило `catalog1(.*)` и он снова редиректит тебя и так до бесконечности, пока ограничения не сработают.

Попробуй так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog1/catalog2/page
RewriteRule ^catalog1/page$ /catalog1/catalog2/page [QSA,L,R=301]
```

**UPD:**

Из комментария, если я правильно понял, сейчас ЧПУ тебе выдает урл только с первым разделом, без остальных вложенностей,используй `#SECTION_PATH#` вместо `#SECTION_CODE#` в настройках инфоблока, где прописывается урл раздела или в настройках компонента

Comment: Тут смысл в том, что page - это внутренние страницы каталога. Их много и задать в правиле конкретно page нельзя. Поэтому $1
И нет, редирект сейчас идёт конкретно на /catalog1/catalog2/

Comment: тогда используй `urlrewrite` Битриксовый

Comment: постой, так у тебя есть разделы и подразделы, а ЧПУ отдает только первый раздел? у тебя в этом проблема?

Comment: обновил ответ, может у тебя в этом проблема